# How to get attributes from SecKeyRef without Password dialog?

Tags: macos

I need to get info about private `kSecAttrKeyType`, `kSecAttrApplicationLabel`, `kSecAttrCanSign`, `kSecAttrCanDecrypt`, `kSecAttrCanUnwrap`, `kSecAttrIsExtractable`

But I've got System password dialog on `SecKeyCopyAttributes` using

[image]

Is there any way to get this public info without System password dialog?

I tried to get some public info from public key. But I've got the same System dialog on `SecKeyCopyPublicKey`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do via `kSecReturnAttributes` parameter of `SecItemCopyMatching` function

Here is C++ example which returns attributes for each key in keychain

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef matchAttr = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                             0,
                                                             &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                             &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionaryAddValue(matchAttr, kSecClass, kSecClassKey);
CFDictionaryAddValue(matchAttr, kSecMatchLimit, kSecMatchLimitAll);
CFDictionaryAddValue(matchAttr, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue);

CFArrayRef result;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(matchAttr, (CFTypeRef*)&result);
if (status == kCCSuccess) {
    CFIndex arrayCount = CFArrayGetCount(result);

    for (CFIndex index = 0; index < arrayCount; index++) {
        CFShow(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(result, index));
    }
}
```